# How to unhide system bar when edittext is clicked

Tags: android

I use code from official android developer forum for enabling fullscreen mode for my app.
I tried to remove some flags, for enabling system bar when I type something in my text fields, but I didn't reach wanted result.
Code I use:

```java
private int currentApiVersion;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        final int flags =
 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        // This work only for android 4.4+
        if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

            // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
            // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
            // show up and won't hide
            final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView
                    .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
```

Now it looks like this

[image: Preview]

But I need it like this 
[image: Preview2]

with bottom system bar for hiding keyboard, when I click on edit.

Comment: Perhaps instead of going through all this removal of the system ui, you could just hide and show your components?

Comment: Is your onWindowFocused change getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Focus change listener to change flags whenever user enters or leaves the edit text. Or use Click listener to change flags whenever user clicks on both. You can also use both. Following is a sample code for both listeners.

```
    emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                // Got Focus
                // Add your code to execute when cursor enters in your edittext
            }else{
                // Lost the Focus
            }
        }
    });

    emailEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // User just clicked on your edit view
        }
    });
```

If you want to change status when user type something, you can use the Text Change listener.

```
    emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            /*
            Called before the changes have been applied to the text.
            The charSequence parameter is the text before any change is applied.
            The start parameter is the position of the beginning of the changed part in the text.
            The count parameter is the length of the changed part in the s sequence since the start position.
            And the after parameter is the length of the new sequence which will replace the part of the s sequence from start to start+count.
            You must not change the text in the TextView from this method (by using myTextView.setText(String newText)).
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            /*
                Similar to the beforeTextChanged method but called after the text changes.
                The charSequence parameter is the text after changes have been applied.
                The start parameter is the same as in the beforeTextChanged method.
                The count parameter is the after parameter in the beforeTextChanged method.
                And the before parameter is the count parameter in the beforeTextChanged method.
                You must not change the text in the TextView from this method (by using myTextView.setText(String newText)).
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            /*
            You can change the text in the TextView from this method.
            /!\ Warning: When you change the text in the TextView, the TextWatcher will be triggered again, starting an infinite loop. You should then add like a boolean _ignore property which prevent the infinite loop.
             */
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try it asap